# Parallax на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, html, parallax

Как сделать parallax на моб. девайсах? При таком коде на любом сенсорном устройстве начинает дергаться:

```js
function parallax(){
            scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
            $('#MainBg').css({
                'transform': "translate(0,"+0+(scrolled*0.55)+"px)"
            });
            requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
        }
```

Comment: Увы но "Parallax scrolling does not always work on mobile devices/smart phones. However, you can use media queries to turn off the effect on mobile devices ". Есть подозрения что расчет идет слишком медленно и потому задержка requestAnimationFrame будет слишком большой. Отсюда и рывковые анимации.

Comment: а как определить пк с 1366px шириной или ipad pro(у него столько же) ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: media query. Например : @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {}

Comment: а это не будет и то и то затрагивать?

Comment: если одинаковая ширина

Comment: Ну для этого это правило и существует. На самом деле можно добавлять дополнительные условия чтобы выделить какие то либо устройства. Почитайте про медиквери - там есть описания случая, который вас волнует (я к сожалению не помню, но кажется что то в meta блоке есть)